# How to create this Kakuro table?

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to write Kakuro, but little bit different, If there is no only one possible
solution, It will count, how many solutions are able to achieve. My problem is to 
create exact table of this shape

```
X     X     16\X  16\X  X     X     15\X  16\X  X     X     X     X
X     X\8   .     .     7\X   X\13  .     .     X     7\X   12\X  X
X     16\17 .     .     .     29\9  .     .     19\15 .     .     X
X\9   .     .     6\23  .     .     .     11\11 .     .     .     X
X\16  .     .     .     23\19 .     .     .     .     9\X   X     X
X     X     X\22  .     .     .     19\8  .     .     .     30\X  6\X
X     X     6\X   15\21 .     .     .     .     11\19 .     .     .
X     X\22  .     .     .     11\21 .     .     .     4\8   .     .
X     X\7   .     .     X\3   .     .     X\9   .     .     .     X
X     X     X     X     X\12  .     .     X     X\12  .     .     X
```

- X means there is no number
- X\number ; number defines sum of numbers on the right side of number
- number1\number2; number 1 is sum of numbers below it; number 2 is sum
- of numbers on the right side of number
- number\X; sum of numbers below it
- . empty space for [1-9]
- there cannot be 2 same numbers in sum of one number
- Max size of Table will be 32x32
- I have to use malloc, realloc and struct in C
- My Idea is to create struct CELL with char*[5], but it is no effective still to use retyping

Comment: To get an answer on this forum, it is usually best to add some code you already tried with problems you ran into (syntactical or conceptual). To ask people to design your problem for you can meet unpleasant reactions. So give it a go, and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a cell is either:

- free for containing any digit between 1 and 9
- non-free; then it is a pair of (optional) sums.